# pkexec won't launch polkit GUI in Lubuntu / LXDE

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, openbox, policykit, pkexec

I performed a fresh install of Lubuntu 12.04 with minimal desktop, [as described here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/Documentation/MinimalInstall).

To clarify, I did a command-line install from the Lubuntu alternative install disc, then I did an `apt-get install --no-install-recommends lubuntu-desktop`.

Everything is working fine, except that Synaptic will not run from the menu entry in the panel.  I am not prompted for a password, and no window of any sort appears after clicking the menu entry.  I installed lxshortcut to see what the shortcut was running, and the command is `synaptic-pkexec`.  If I type this command into the "Run" menu, I get the same behavior (or lack thereof).

I can get Synaptic to open up just fine by typing `gksudo synaptic` at the "Run" menu.  Also, if I run "synaptic-pkexec" from the terminal, then I am prompted for my password within the terminal, and after that Synaptic opens normally.

Can someone please suggest the right way to get Synaptic working?  I could just change the menu entry to "gksudo synaptic", but I'm guessing that it's set to `synaptic-pkexec` for a reason.  I have a vague understanding that this `pkexec` business has something to do with PolicyKit, but I don't really know what PolicyKit is or how to tell if something is broken with it.

Comment: This was a bug in Ubuntu 11.10, same exact scenario... it's discussed here - http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1827093

Maybe running an update would resolve it?

Comment: Can you start synaptic from terminal ?
If you can't , enter output in here.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  According to that thread, the bug was fixed in synaptic-0.75.2ubuntu6.  Running "apt-cache policy synaptic" says I have 0.75.9ubuntu1 installed.  "apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade" says I'm fully up to date.

Comment: Try re-installing Synaptic.

Comment: Just tried "apt-get install --reinstall synaptic".  The process completed successfully, but it did not change the behavior of synaptic.  The problem still exists, I'm afraid.

Comment: Do other programs, run manually with `pkexec`, also do authentication in the command-line rather than graphcially? For example, what happens when you run `pkexec ls` in the Terminal? Do you get non-graphical authentication for that, too? The default behavior of `pkexec` is to authenticate graphically when possible (even if running a nongraphical command like `ls`), so if that also gives you non-graphical authentication, it seems likely this is either a **local configuration problem**, or a **bug**, in `pkexec`/PolicyKit.

Comment: The trouble does seem to be with pkexec.  "pkexec ls" from the Run menu (Alt+F2) does nothing.  "pkexec ls" from the terminal authenticates within the terminal and then succeeds.  I also tried another GUI program from the Run menu, "pkexec pcmanfm", and this does nothing.  How would I go about configuring pkexec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to install the `policykit-1-gnome` package.  Once I installed this package and rebooted, Synaptic worked normally.

I installed the complete Lubuntu desktop in a VM for comparison with my minimal installation, and that's how I discovered what was missing.  According to the package description:

> PolicyKit-gnome provides a D-Bus session bus service that is used to bring up authentication dialogs used for obtaining privileges.

Obviously, without the described functionality, I was never going to get a GUI authentication prompt to open Synaptic.

`synaptic` is a dependency of the `lubuntu-desktop` metapackage, so it was installed by default in my minimal installation.  Shouldn't `policykit-1-gnome` be a dependency of `lubuntu-desktop` as well, since Synaptic won't work without it?  Do you think I should report a bug?

Comment: Excellent work tracking down the cause of the problem! And yes, I think you should [report this as a bug](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs). My Lubuntu systems installed from the Lubuntu desktop CD don't have this problem; they probably come with `policykit-1-gnome` installed separately from any other packages. It's set to manually installed (and I didn't install it myself). If you report a bug, please update your answer with the bug link.

Comment: I'm getting this exact same problem running a minimal install of ubuntu using standalone compiz session with Unity. Thing is, I have policykit-1-gnome installed, but its still not working.

Comment: For whatever reason, if you're running lubuntu/lxde and openbox, this package is marked for removal during an upgrade (you do have the option to keep packages during the upgrade). Installing `policykit-1-gnome` and logging out/in provides the GUI that `pkexec` wants to launch. Question edited to better reflect the problem, because this post is somewhat difficult to find and the problem is not due to `synaptic` in any way.

Comment: Ok, so, I assume the two other computers I've run this same setup on and never had to jump through a million hoops to get the menu to work, I must have just been lucky, or something?

Answer (score 4):

I am using an alternative solution to the accepted answer. I prefer using `lxpolkit` instead of `policykit-1-gnome` since it is designed for LXDE.

This problem with `pkexec` not launching the authentication screen is very common. The first thing to check is whether you have a graphical policy kit interface (either `lxpolkit` or `policykit-1-gnome`) installed and configured for LXDE because these packages are flagged to be removed during a major upgrade of lubuntu. Apparently neither are included when installing the distro.

### Solution

- Install `lxpolkit`.
  `sudo apt-get install lxpolkit`
- Logout and login.
- Set `lxpolkit` as default policy agent
  In the menu, go to `Preferences > Default applications for LXSession` (or run `lxsession-default-apps` in a terminal). In the first section "Running applications" (**Update: Default apps manager 14.10 is different. Use the `Core applications` tab.**), go to the option for `Polkit agent` and make sure lxpolkit is selected.

Instead of using the package `policykit-1-gnome`, `lxsession` will now use `lxpolkit` for LXDE.

[image: LXPolkit screenshot]

### Why Apps Launched With `pkexec` Don't Run From the LXDE Menu

It comes down to the way apps in the X11 system are launched with **pkexec**.

The apps that appear in the lxpanel menu are stored and configured in either `/usr/share/applications` (global menus items) or `~/.local/share/applications` (user specific). See [LXDE Wiki - Main Menu](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Menu)

In these directories you will find a .desktop file for each of the applications appearing in your menu. Here is an example of `/usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop`:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Synaptic Package Manager
GenericName=Package Manager
Comment=Install, remove and upgrade software packages
Exec=synaptic-pkexec
Icon=synaptic
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=PackageManager;GTK;System;Settings;
NotShowIn=KDE;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=synaptic
```

Notice the line **`Exec=synaptic-pkexec`**.

In the absence of a policy kit interface, the user is normally asked for a password in the command line. Since this is a menu item, this is launched in the background and there is no command line to enter the password. Hence, you need to make sure you are using `lxpolkit`. Or if you prefer the gnome polkit, install the package `policykit-1-gnome` which launches the login menu whenever `pkexec` is used. I have removed the package `policykit-1-gnome` and using `lxpolkit` works well for all applications.

### Alternative Solutions

**Use gksudo Instead of pkexec**
You could right-click applications like synaptic in the menu, click Properties, and change the Command field from `synaptic-pkexec` to `gksudo synaptic`. Or via command line, copy the original file to your user's applications directory with `sudo cp /usr/share/applications/synaptic.desktop ${HOME}/.local/share/applications/synaptic.desktop`

Then edit the line `Exec=synaptic-pkexec` and replace it with `Exec=gksudo synaptic`

gksudo's "primary purpose is to run graphical commands that need root without the need to run an X terminal emulator and using su directly." - [GKSU(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/gksu)

And for good reason! See [Running Sudo Graphically](http://psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo).

This of course requires that every application relying on pkexec be edited to launch with gksudo which requires more work on your part if you're using lxpanel. A nice comparison of security and usability features for gksudo and PolicyKit can be found at [Comparison of privilege authorization features](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_privilege_authorization_features).

**Write Your Own `pkexec` Policy For Individual Applications**
This is more than I want to do, but it may be useful in some situations. I don't recommend doing this without a strong understanding of [writing PolicyKit Actions](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Polkit#Actions).

> The actions available to you via polkit will depend on the packages
>   you have installed. Some are used in multiple desktop environments
>   (org.freedesktop.*), some are DE-specific (org.gnome.*) and some are
>   specific to a single program (org.archlinux.pkexec.gparted.policy).
>   The command pkaction lists all the actions defined in
>   /usr/share/polkit-1/actions for quick reference.

Here's an example, which I have not tested, from [City-busz -Using 'pkexec' command instead of 'gksu'](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=999328#p999328):

> E.g. if you want to run gparted as root with
>
> ```
> $ pkexec gparted
> ```
>
> command, then create a new file
>
> ```
> /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.policy
> ```
>
> with the following content:
>
> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <!DOCTYPE policyconfig PUBLIC
>  "-//freedesktop//DTD PolicyKit Policy Configuration 1.0//EN"
>  "http://www.freedesktop.org/standards/PolicyKit/1/policyconfig.dtd">
> <policyconfig>
>
>   <action id="org.freedesktop.policykit.pkexec.run-gparted">
>     <description>Run GParted</description>
>     <message>Authentication is required to run GParted</message>
>     <defaults>
>       <allow_any>no</allow_any>
>       <allow_inactive>no</allow_inactive>
>       <allow_active>auth_admin_keep</allow_active>
>     </defaults>
>     <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.path">/usr/sbin/gparted</annotate>
>     <annotate key="org.freedesktop.policykit.exec.allow_gui">TRUE</annotate>
>   </action>
>
> </policyconfig>
> ```
>
> More actions can be added into the same file.

Hat tip to [renegat at archlinux.org](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1320449#p1320449) for compiling relevant excerpts from related LXDE and PolicyKit documentation that ultimately led me to using LXPolkit as the preferred solution.

Answer (score 0):

Used the suggestion to right click the synaptic entry in the menu under System Tools, choose Properties, then Desktop Entry tab and change synaptic-pkexec to gksudo synaptic.

That didn't work, so I investigated via terminal running synaptic (gksudo synaptic).

For me, trying to use gksudo resulted in a message telling me how to install gksu.  When I tried installing, it resulted in a message saying that gksu was already installed (and still didn't work).  I uninstalled gksu and reinstalled, and now synaptic works fine.

Comment: That sounds like a great solution except for two things: `bash: gksudo: command not found` and from apt, 'E: unable to locate package gksudo.` But if gksudo existed, it sounds like it would really solve the problem!