# php7.0-zip not installing the package

Tags: zip

While composer install I'm getting error

> magento/product-community-edition 2.1.10 requires ext-zip * -> the
>   requested PHP extension zip is missing from your system.

So I'm installing the zip extention using:

> sudo apt-get install php7.0-zip

I'm getting below error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
php7.0-zip : Depends: php7.0-common (= 7.0.4-7ubuntu2) but 7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

My PHP version is: `PHP 7.0.18-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli)`

I have followed below url to fix this but no luck..

[php7.0-zip packages have unmet dependencies](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1127455/php7-0-zip-packages-have-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: Please download `php7.0-common_7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb (821.6 KiB)` from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/amd64/php7.0-common/7.0.18-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 and install this depedency.